# Prebuild native addon dependencies (for node and electron)

Tags: node.js, node-gyp, node.js-addon, prebuild, n-api

I'm trying to use a native addon ([Node Sentinel File Watcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nsfw) -a.k.a. NSFW-) in a node application and also in an electron application.

Using the same native addon with both (node and electron) doesn't work, so I have to rebuild the addon using [electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild) (then it will work with electron) or `npm rebuild` (then it will work for node), but not for both at the same time.

I'm trying to avoid having to rebuild for switching, and I prefer to have a dynamic require depending on the platform (and I will use one specific version of electron).

Is it possible to install a dependency prebuilding it for two (or more) platforms at the same time?

I found some interesting packages like https://www.npmjs.com/package/prebuild but it looks like you need to modify the native addon (in this case NSFW).

I'm planning to use this as a private NPM package that will be distributed and used for node and for one specific version of electron.

Comment: Not the biggest expert in N-API here, but I handle lots of different production build setups in a monorepo (with NodeJS APIs, React Native, Vue and CLIs). I've fought this war for some time now and the experience I have is to create separate packages for each target, with third package acting as a common layer for shareable code. It requires more work but can be accomplished relatively easier than inside a single package (retargeting builds in runtime for example with a postinstall script). I can elaborate more with more info, is it a prod or dev dependency? Is it needed in the bundled app?

Comment: I know the question is old, but may still be relevant for future visitors.

Comment: Thank you Luis, I added an answer about how I resolved it (it was a long time ago), I agree it's possible to solve it manually without any lib, generating several builds and requiring it in runtime (it's what node-pre-gyp does).

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to fork the library and used [prebuildify](https://github.com/prebuild/prebuildify) to generate several prebuilds; another alternative was to use node-pre-gyp but there are some problems with it and webpack, so I prefered to use prebuildify instead.